# 一定の時間が立ってから文字列をコンソール上に出力したい

Tags: java

題名にもある通り、下記の「Hello Java」と言う文字列を他の文字列よりも200ミリ秒ほど後に出力をしたいです。
JavascriptのjQueryでいう、`fadeIn(200);` みたいな実行結果にしたいです。
Googleで調べてみたところ、Threadというのを使えば良いのでしょうか？
誰かお力添えいただけると幸いです。

```
public class Main{
  public static void main ( String[] args ){
    System.out.println("Hello World"); // 普通の文字列の出力
    
    System.out.println("Hello Java");  // 200ミリ秒遅れてからの出力
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200ミリ秒を人間が認識できるかは微妙ですが、時間を置いて処理を実行したい場合は `sleep` を使うのが簡単かと思います。

```
// 処理1

try {
    Thread.sleep(200); // 単位: ミリ秒で指定
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}

// 処理2
```

参考:
[Javaでプログラムを一時停止、Thread.sleepの使い方と仕組みを解説](https://www.bold.ne.jp/engineer-club/java-sleep)